# Nativescript TS - Ontap not changing label value in render

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm re-learning the ropes of Nativescript, having not touched it since v4.

I'm trying to update the value of my label when I tap the button. When I console out, I can see the value change in the model, but it's not reflected on the screen.

My files below:

home-page.ts

```
import { NavigatedData, Page } from "@nativescript/core";

import { HomeViewModel } from "./home-view-model";

export function navigatingTo(args: NavigatedData): void {
    if (args.isBackNavigation) {
        return;
    }

    const page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
}
```

home-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
    <ActionBar title="NativeFlix" />
    <StackLayout height="100%">
        <TextField hint="Enter Something" text="{{ _geo_longitude }}"/>
        <Label text="{{ _geo_longitude }}"/>
        <Button tap="{{ onTap }}" text="Button"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

home-view-model.ts

```
import {
  Frame,
  Observable,
  ObservableArray,
  ItemEventData,
} from "@nativescript/core";

export class HomeViewModel extends Observable {
    public _geo_longitude: number;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async onTap(args: ItemEventData): Promise<void> {
        console.log("OnTap Triggered")
        console.log( this._geo_longitude )
        this._geo_longitude = 123213;
    }
}
```

Guidance on what I'm doing wrong, and some pointers to documentation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your tap event in Button is not binded right. Notice the parantheses around "tap"...

```
<Button text="Tap me!" (tap)="onTap($event)"></Button>
```